# JSS vueJs - How to include vue-meta for server rendering

Tags: jss

JSS Tech preview 3
vueJs sample basic

I'm looking to include **vue-meta** for Server Rendering.

I've successfully added it for Client Rendering, but, because the tutorial to include vue-meta is very different that what we have in JSS I don't know how to include it for Server Rendering.

[https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta](https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta#step-2-server-rendering-optional)

What I have done so far:
 - I added 4 fields ( meta ) in routes.sitecore.js:
 - [image: List item]
 - App.vue:
 - [image: List item]
 - data/routes/en.json
 - [image: List item]
 - boot/Root.js
 - [image: List item]

If I follow the steps in the documentation of vue-meta, how should I convert their example to the code you have for JSS ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE - JSS TECH PREVIEW 4

The [Vue sample app](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/tree/master/samples/vue) for JSS Tech Preview 4 uses `vue-meta` for managing meta fields in both SSR and client-side rendering.

For the specific usage of `vue-meta` and SSR, see the [`server/server.js` file](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/master/samples/vue/server/server.js).

---

## JSS TECH PREVIEW 3

The `vue-meta` docs use `bundleRenderer` for SSR as opposed to just the "standard" renderer, but based on this example code: https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta/blob/master/examples/ssr.js, it looks like you'd need to make a few modifications to `src/server.js`:

```
// the following code would be in the `.then((content)` chain after `renderer.renderToString(app)`
// where `app` is a Vue instance, and assumes you've already registered the Meta plugin elsewhere via Vue.use(Meta);
const meta = app.$meta().inject();
const serverComponent = new Vue({
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(ServerHtml, {
      props: {
        content,
        initialState: validRouteOrNull,
        distPath: __BUNDLE_OUTPUT_PATH__,
        meta, // pass the meta object as prop to `ServerHtml`
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Then in `src/app/ServerHtml.js` you'd be able to add/reference the `meta` prop and render the necessary meta data to the server-generated html. e.g.

```
...
props: {
  ...
  meta: {
    type: Object
  },
},
render() {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>{this.meta.title.text()}</title>
      </head>
      ...
    </html>        
  )
}
...
```

DISCLAIMER: this code has *not* been tested, it's ad-hoc based on the `vue-meta` docs and JSS sample code.

Comment: Hi @adam, I've tried to include your code and I've this error when deploying : https://imgur.com/a/JqtCcCZ

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like you have `app` locally scoped in your promise chain, e.g. `.then((app) => ()`, so `app` will only be available within that `then` function. You'll either need to hoist `app` up outside of the promise chain so that any `.then` function can reference it, or explicitly pass it along through the chain. Again, this is all untested, ad-hoc code, so you may have to do some massaging to get it right or make it work. Just trying to help you find the right direction.

Comment: An example of passing `app` along to the next `.then` function:
https://gist.github.com/aweber1/807aedfa0472faffb527fdc5b68aa87f

Comment: We are really close, because your code return : &lt;title data-vue-meta=&quot;true&quot;&gt;Page | Site&lt;/title&gt;

Comment: Cool. That seems like an implementation detail best left to be worked out by you and the vue-meta library. It looks like the vue-meta plugin is wired up correctly and rendering some sort of title content but invocation / syntax is probably not correct given that the code is not "formal". Again, the code provided is untested and ad-hoc. If you find the final correct format/syntax, please share :)